# JavaScript - Best way to have multiple events fire at different timings

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals, node-red

I'm working on a Node-red flow (which basically uses nodejs, so JavaScript-based) that reads several sensors at different intervals and triggers other various events.

Instead of having a timer for each event to fire at specific frequency (I was afraid it would cause lag), I have one single timer that increments seconds indefinitely, and at every second,  each event is doing a modulo operation to see if they should fire.

This seems janky as multiple divisions occur each second. Furthermore, as the integer value gets bigger, I'm afraid those divisions will get slower and the integer will eventually overflow its max value after running for long periods of time.

So I'm now second-guessing my approach and asking the community if individual timers are actually better for performance, or if there's an even better way to do this. For the record, I will have maybe 20-40 events to fire at different intervals.

Comment: `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740990` -  `Date.now()` is only ~1/5000th of the way there, shouldn't be any need to worry about overflow for quite a long time :)

Comment: `that increments seconds indefinitely`  It might take a while for this to overflow :)  I work out that would be about 285616414 years.

Comment: Good point haha! I hadn't calculated that ;) so that part isn't an issue at least!

Comment: JavaScript uses 64-bits for every number, if your timer counts milliseconds, your page can stay operational for around 290 million years, I think it's safe to say you don't need to worry about counter overflow. Furthermore, modulo is a constant time operation with regard to the size of its input -- modulo of a larger number isn't computed slower than modulo of a smaller number.